# Google индексирует только часть сайта

Tags: seo, интернет-магазин, поисковая-оптимизация, google-search

Привет! Имеется сайт на битриксе, тематика - интернет-магазин, на хостинге лежит около 6 месяцев. Проблема следующая: гугл индексирует около 100 страниц из 19000, с яндексом в свою очередь проблем нет. Где-то месяц назад примерно 10 товаров всё таки было проиндексировано, а потом товары вовсе перестали индексироваться. Есть подозрение, что бот гугла, в моём случае, индексирует страницы, ссылки на которые есть только на главной странице.

Вот скриншот статистики индексации из гугловской консоли:
[image: Скриншот статистики индексации из Google Search Console]

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Сделайте sitemap https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

Comment: ilux, sitemap присутствует, сгенерированный битриксом. На скриншоте статистика по этому sitemap'y.